# Нарисовать башенку заданой высоты

Tags: java

Написать функцию, которая принимает целое число, и выводит на экран “башенку” заданной высоты - (на [рисунке](https://postimg.org/image/v5vl1gv2n/) передано функции число 5)

```
1      ## ##
2     ### ###
3    #### ####
4   ##### #####
5  ###### ######
```

У меня получилась вот так

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pyramyda {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Введите число строк для построения пирамидки");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = in.nextInt();
        String n = "#";
        for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
           for (int k = input; k > 0; k--) {
               System.out.print( " " );
           }
           n = n + "#";
           System.out.println( n + " " + n );
        }
    }
}
```

Но что- то не так строит

Comment: башенка вот такая должна получиться https://postimg.cc/image/v5vl1gv2n/

Comment: [внезапный-codegolf]

Comment: Кто напишет на streams API?

Comment: ващет в программинге все перечисления нужно с 0 начинать, даже для примера. Отвечаю, так лучше понимается

Comment: Спасибо всем огромное!!! Задача решена

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^"

Answer (score 3):

Вот этот код строит правильно:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j< input - i - 1; j++) {
            System.out.print( " " );
        }
        n = n + "#";
        System.out.println( n + " " + n );
    }
```

Результат:

```
    ## ##
   ### ###
  #### ####
 ##### #####
###### ######
```

Answer (score 3):

> Кто напишет на streams API?

Ну почему бы и нет?

При использовании StringUtils от apache:

```
    System.out.println(Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1).limit(input)
        .map(k -> StringUtils.repeat(" ", input - k) +
                  StringUtils.repeat("#", k) + " " +
                  StringUtils.repeat("#", k))
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```

Или вообще так (без StringUtils)

```
    System.out.println(Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1)
       .limit(input)
       .map(k -> 
          Stream.concat(
            Collections.nCopies(input - k, " ").stream(),
            Stream.concat(
                Collections.nCopies(k, "#").stream(),
                Stream.concat(
                  Collections.nCopies(1, " ").stream(),
                  Collections.nCopies(k, "#").stream()
                )
            )
           ).collect(Collectors.joining(""))
        ).collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```

Comment: Так нечестно, я тоже хотел использовать функцию, которая создаёт строку с повторяющимся символом. Но не нашёл. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Во вторым цикле условие неправильное. Нужно пробелов добавлять в зависимости от номера строки, а у вас во всех строках одинаковое количество. Нужно с `i` сравнивать, а не `0`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pyramyda {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Введите число строк для построения пирамидки");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = in.nextInt();
        String n = "#";
        for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
           for (int k = input - 1; k > i; k--) {
               System.out.print( " " );
           }
           n = n + "#";
           System.out.println( n + " " + n );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Лишний пробел у вас будет вначале каждой строки, правильнее for (int k = input - 1; k > i; k--) {

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin благодарю, поправил ^^"

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот вроде бы довольно короткий способ без вложенных циклов:

```
String format = "%1$" + (input + 1) + "s %1s\n";
String hashes = "#";
for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
    hashes = hashes + "#";
    System.out.format(format, hashes);
}
```

Проверка: https://ideone.com/tCVfYc

Comment: У вас тоже лишний пробел в начале каждой строки, посмотрите внимательнее

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin: Ну я специально вставил пробел в начале форматной строки, у ТС в примере он тоже есть. Если что, можно убрать :)

Answer (score 2):

Гольф так гольф (81 без пробелов и переводов строк. h - входной параметр) :)

```
String t = "#", f = "%" + h + "s# #%-" + h + "s\n";
for(; h-- > 0; t += "#") System.out.printf(f, t, t);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Введите число строк для построения пирамидки");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = in.nextInt();
    String n = "#";
    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < input-i; k++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        n = n + "#";
        System.out.println(n + " " + n);
    }
}
```

Comment: меняйте 2 цикл, иначе никак...

Comment: Вы можете редактировать собственный ответ ^_^

Comment: вместо  input - i должно быть input - i -1 иначе лишний пробел будет